# python: Small Logical Error in a terminal function graphing class

Tags: python, function, math, graphing

`    I am creating a personal graphing system for in terminal use.  The class goes as follows:

```
import parser
def ev(n, x):
code = parser.expr(n).compile()
return eval(code)


class Graph:
def __init__(self, length, width):
    self.l = length
    self.w = width
    self.graph = [['-' for x in range(self.w)] for x in range(self.l)]
def draw(self):
    for i in range(self.l):
        temp = []
        for j in range(self.w):
            temp.append(self.graph[i][j])
        print ''.join(temp)

def add(self, f):
    y = []
    for i in range(self.w):
        y.append(ev(f, i))
    top = max(y)
    bot = min(y)
    print y
    scale = (top - bot)/self.l
    print scale

    adj = 0
    for i in range(self.l,0,1):
        adj = bot + (i * scale)
        for j in y:
            if j >= adj & j < adj + scale:
                self.graph[i][j] = 'X'
```

all runs well except the add module, which creates a range of y values from a pre defined function to parse an equation i.e "x**2" in the last 6 lines of code, it fails, no points in the graph array are modified to 'X'

if anyone would be so kind as to perhaps run and assist, That would be great

Comment: Format the question properly, and tag it with the programming language in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems:

```
scale = (top - bot)/self.l
```

Depending on your version of Python this might do an integer division, so cast to float to make sure you don't round down to zero:

```
scale = (top - bot)/float(self.l)
```

Also, subtracting one can avoid an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) (an array of n items has n-1 steps when iterating from the first to the last element).

```
scale = (top - bot)/float(self.l-1)
```

Your range is incorrect (first parameter should be the start value)

```
for i in range(0,self.l,1):
```

Lastly, the `&` should be an `and` (`&` is the bitwise and operator)

```
if j >= adj and j < adj + scale:
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in this line:

```
for i in range(self.l,0,1):
```

`range(some_positive_value, 0, 1)` will yield the empty list; you probably want `range(0, self.l, 1)` which is the equivalent of `range(self.l)`. For more info type `help(range)` in the python console. Also for python versions older than 3 use `xrange` instead of `range`.